# JQuery Validate Submit handler not firing .done

Tags: jquery, json

I have a form which uses JQuery Validate.  My submitHandler looks like the following

```
submitHandler: function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "backend/process.php",
        data: {
            'clientName': $("#clientName").val()
        },
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function (response) {
        alert("DONE");
        alert(response);
        if(response == 'success') {
            alert("YES");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

So this data is sent to process.php.  This file does the following

```
<?php

include 'classes/ClientHandler.php';

$c_name = $_POST['clientName'];


$clientHandler = new ClientHandler();
$response = $clientHandler->insertClient($c_name);
var_dump($response);

if($response == "success"){
    return "success";
}
```

Within my ClientHandler class, I insert the data into a Database and return if its successful.

```
public function insertClient($c_name) {
    try {
        /* Database code */
        return "success";
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        trigger_error("Failed to create client: " . $e->getMessage(), E_USER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

I am not showing all my code so it's not to much, but the above should demonstrate my process.  My data is successfully added to my db.

I have just added a fail to the handler, and this triggers an alert I set up in fail.  It states

> Status: parsererror Error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected
>   character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Is there anything in my code that may be causing this error?

Thanks

Comment: Is your PHP actually returning a JSON result? It appears not.

Comment: Perfect, you can mark as the answer - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **process.php**, replace your :

> `return "success";`

by

> `echo json_encode("success");`

You have to write your data, so you can use **echo**.

If you use the **return** statement, you return some data at the server level.